# tikzpicture working in a document and not working in another one

Tags: circuitikz

I was writing a book and used to draw some circuits on it. Now I'm working in a bachelor thesis and when I try to copy/paste the same drawing (using the same packages) it doesn't work.

```
   \documentclass[
        % -- memoir class options --
        12pt,               % tamanho da fonte
        openright,          % capítulos começam em pág ímpar (insere página vazia caso preciso)
        oneside,            % para impressão em verso e anverso. Oposto a oneside % modifcado
        a4paper,            % tamanho do papel
        english,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
        french,             % idioma adicional para hifenização
        spanish,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
        brazil              % o último idioma é o principal do documento
        ]{abntex2}

        \usepackage{graphicx}           % Inclusão de gráficos
        \usepackage{amsmath,indentfirst}            % for matrices
        \usepackage{algorithm}
        \usepackage{listings}
        \usepackage{subcaption}                     % Customizing Listing
        \usepackage{tabu}
        \usepackage{siunitx}
        \usepackage{pgfplots}                       % axis
        \usepackage{polynom}                        % for \polylongdiv{}
        \usepackage{esint}
        \usepackage{amssymb}                       
        \usepackage{array}
        \usepackage{steinmetz}
        \usepackage{circuitikz}
        \usepackage{tikz}

        \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, shapes.arrows,decorations.pathmorphing, matrix,chains,scopes,positioning,fit,shapes.gates.logic.US, shapes.gates.logic.IEC, calc,
        decorations.markings,arrows.meta,bending}

\begin{document}

        \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) to[short,o-] (0.7,0) to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.9cm,R] (2,0) to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.9cm,L] (3.3,0)  to[short,-*] (4,0) to[short,-*] (5.4,0) to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.9cm,L] (6.7,0)
            (6.7,-2.5) to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.9cm,vR] (6.7,0)
            (4,0) -- (4,-0.5) -- (4.4, -0.5)
            to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.9cm,L] (4.4,-2) -- (4,-2) -- (4,-2.5) to[short,-*] (5.4,-2.5) -- (6.7,-2.5)
            (4,-0.5) -- (3.6, -0.5) to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.9cm,R] (3.6,-2) -- (4,-2) to[short,-*] (4,-2.5) to[short,-o] (0,-2.5);

        \draw (-0.15,0.6) node {$\hat{I}_1$};
        \draw (4.8,0.6) node {$\hat{I}_2$};
        \draw (0,-0.3) node {$+$};
        \draw (0,-1.1) node {$\hat{V}_1$};
        \draw (0,-2.3) node {$-$};
        \draw (1.25,0.4) node {$R_1$};
        \draw (2.55,0.4) node {$X_1$};
        \draw (6.05,0.4) node {$X_2$};
        \draw (7.3,-1.25) node {$\displaystyle{\frac{R_2}{s}}$};
        \draw (3.1,-1) node {$G_c$};
        \draw (5,-1) node {$B_m$};
        \draw (5.5,-0.4) node {$+$};
        \draw (5.5,-1.1) node {$\hat{E}_2$};    
        \draw (5.5,-2.3) node {$-$};
        \draw (2.9,-1.7) node {$\hat{I}_c$};    
        \draw (5.05,-1.7) node {$\hat{I}_m$};

        \draw (-0.5,0.25) -- (0,0.25)
            (3.27,-1.35) -- (3.27,-1.85)
            (4.68,-1.35) -- (4.68,-1.85);

        \draw[-latex] (4.55,0.25) -- (5.05,0.25);

        \draw[fill=black] (0,0.3) -- (0,0.2) -- (0.15,0.25) -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=black] (4.6,-1.85) -- (4.75,-1.85) -- (4.68,-1.98) -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=black] (3.20,-1.85) -- (3.34,-1.85) -- (3.27,-1.99) -- cycle;

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}

    \end{document}
```

The original drawing:

[image]

The error types:

> ! Package tikz Error: + or - expected.See the tikz package
>   documentation for explanation.Type H  for immediate help....
>   \draw (0,0) to[short,o-] (0.7,0)
>
> ! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a
>   semicolon?.See the tikz package documentation for explanation.Type H
>    for immediate help.... \draw (0,0) to[short,o-] (0.7,0)
>
> ! Undefined control sequence.\pgf@let@token ...ape,
>   rotate=\pgf@circ@direction, yscale=\ctikzvalof {mirr... \draw (0,0)
>   to[short,o-] (0.7,0)
>
> ! Argument of \pgf@circ@stripdecimals has an extra }.\par \draw (0,0) to[short,o-] (0.7,0)
>
> ! Missing number, treated as zero.p \draw (0,0)
>   to[short,o-] (0.7,0)

and a lot more =/
What could I do?

Comment: It worked fine for me, using \documentclass{article}.

Comment: It works with up-to-date packages, so I would guess that the computer where this doesn't work has older versions of `circuitikz` or `pgf`, and if that is the case then updating would solve it. To figure out which versions you have on the two computers, you can add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass`,  and look at the `*File list*` near the end of the `.log` file. You don't need  all the text to get that though, make a document such as `\listfiles \documentclass{...} <all of your packages etc.> \begin{document} foo \end{document}` and compile that, then look at the `.log` file.

Comment: @JohnKormylo So maybe the mistake is to use a differente class here...

Comment: Hi! We need to know more about the *other* document. `:)`

Comment: Hm I see French  and Spanish there! It's probably related to the TikZ `shortandoff-on` thingy... Try adding `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`, out of curiosity...

Comment: @PauloCereda I guess the main difference is that the other document uses \documentclass{report}

Comment: @FranciscoMaerle: don't think so, `report` works on my end as well... `:(`

Comment: @PauloCereda IT WORKED!!!!!! I was also wondering why this languages (French and Spanish) were making mistakes when erased it... Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad it worked! We ducks are very good at solving problems. `:)` Some languages change category codes which might potentially interfere with TikZ diagrams, that's why they decided to include a `babel` library that addresses this issue.